# NodeJS programmatically read the CNAME file created for custom domains in Github Pages

Tags: node.js, git

Assuming that I will be deploying my static site to a branch `gh-pages` to a remote Git repo with the remote `origin`, and there's a file in the root directory called `CNAME`, how can I read the contents of just this file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to deploy the static page to Github Pages, you do not need to programmatically read the file. Github handles this for you if you add your custom domain under the repository options, as long as you have pushed CNAME to `remote`.

I'm not sure why you would otherwise want to read the contents of the CNAME file, but if the above answer wasn't satisfactory, let me know, and I might be able to help you out further.